# c++ Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: c++

This returns a Segmentation Fault 11, I can't seem to figure out whats causing the error.

The code doesnt error out until it tries to output the Red Blue Green to the file, I dont think indexing into a vector should use up all the remaining memory but I cant seems to put my finger on what is causing the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

const int PIX_SIZE = 40;
const int ESCAPE = 1024;
const char FILEOUTPUT[64] = "juliaOutput";
const char COLORFILE[64] = "juliaColor";




void juliaOutput(){
    std::ofstream fout(FILEOUTPUT);
    fout << PIX_SIZE << ' ' << PIX_SIZE << ' ' << ESCAPE << std::endl;

    double dx = 4./(PIX_SIZE-1);
    double dy = 4./(PIX_SIZE-1);

    double a =.5;
    double b = -.5;

    double row;
    double col;

    int count;

    for(row=2; row>=-2; row-=dy){
        for(col=-2; col<=2; col+=dx){
            count = 0;
            double new_x = col;
            double new_y = row;
            while(((new_x*new_x) + (new_y*new_y) <= 4) && count <= ESCAPE-1){
                double old_x = new_x;
                double old_y = new_y;
                new_x = (old_x*old_x) - (old_y*old_y) + a;
                new_y = (2*old_x*old_y) + b;
                count++;
            }
            fout << count << ' ';   
        }
        fout << std::endl;
    }
    fout.close();
}

void makeColors(std::vector<int> red, std::vector<int>  blue, std::vector<int>  green){
    int i;
    for(i =0; i < 1025; i++){
        if(i <= 255){
            red.push_back(i);
            green.push_back(25);
            blue.push_back(25);
        }
        if(i >= 256 && i <= 511){
            red.push_back(25);
            green.push_back(i-256);
            blue.push_back(25);
        }
        if(i >= 512 && i <= 767){
            red.push_back(25);
            green.push_back(25);
            blue.push_back(i-512);
        }
        if(i >= 768 && i <= 1023){
            red.push_back(100);
            green.push_back(i-768);
            blue.push_back(100);
        }
        else{
            red.push_back(255);
            green.push_back(255);
            blue.push_back(255);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Colors Profiles Created" << std::endl;
}

void assignColors(){

    std::vector<int> red;
    std::vector<int> green;
    std::vector<int> blue;

    makeColors(red, green, blue);

    std::ifstream fin(FILEOUTPUT);
    std::ofstream fout(COLORFILE);

    std::string line;
    size_t i = 0;
    while(std::getline(fin, line)){
        if(i > 0){
            fout << red[i] << ' ' << green[i] << ' ' << blue[i] << '\n';
            i += 1;
        }
        else{
            fout << line << '\n';
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();

}

int main(){

    juliaOutput();
    assignColors();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger first to step through and identify which line of your code causes the error please. That's your part of the job, not ours.

Comment: If your question is "how do you debug a segmentation fault", we don't need to see your code. If the question is about your code, what is the question exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to c++ I haven't ever used a debugger for c++.

Comment: @Bytehunter Hurry up to learn how to use it, that's a **very essential** skill.

Comment: I've only a couple weeks into learning c++, what is your preferred debugger? I have only been learning to write code for a short time, school courses are requiring I learn c++, x86 assembly and python at the same time. Sorry for the limited knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting the function `makeColors` to modify the vectors, but you pass all the arguments by value.  You can change:

```
void makeColors(std::vector<int> red, std::vector<int> blue, std::vector<int> green)
```

to

```
void makeColors(std::vector<int>& red, std::vector<int>& blue, std::vector<int>& green)
```

to pass by reference instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it.